# Proof: If a|b, then a|bc.

Tags: proof-explanation, divisibility, solution-verification

I’m in the beginning stages of an intro to proofs class, so please bear with me. I’ll write what I have thus far.

*Proof*:

Let us suppose a|b. Then there exists an integer b such that b = ak. For a|bc, there must be an integer m such that bc=am.

Thus we have:

bc = am
   = (ak)m

What I’m unclear with is that, if I solve for *m*, I’ll end up wit bc/ak, which doesn’t exactly help my case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The line $bc=am=(ak)m$ isn't right.  The last expressions should be $(ak)c$

Comment: So what role, then, does *m* play here? Or would *m* simply be equal to *(ak)c*?

Comment: No, $m=kc$.  If $b = ak$, multiply both sides by $c$ to get $bc=(ak)c=a(kc)$.

Answer (score 1):

> Let us suppose a|b. Then there exists an integer b such that b = ak. For a|bc, there must be an integer m such that bc=am.

You're right up until the final sentence (on the premise you meant to reference $k$ in the second sentence). *A priori,* there is no reason for such an integer $m$ to exist.

Instead, what you might find fruitful as an angle is that, by multiplying both sides by $c$,

$$a|b \implies b = ak \implies bc = akc \implies a|bc$$

Why? Since the product of integers are integers, which $a,b,c,k$ are assumed to be, $kc \in \Bbb Z$. Therefore, there exists an integer $m := kc$ such that $bc=am$. (Bear in mind the definition for divisibility, $x|y \implies x = yz$ for some integer $z$.)

Comment: The line you quoted should say, "there exists an integer $k$ ..."

Comment: Thank you for your insightful explanation, I finally understood what was going on.